# Recognize different Objects Types Facebook API

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to ask if there is a way to recognize what a user is looking from a request to the Facebook Graph.

For example:

Request for a Note:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/122788341354
```

Request for an Event:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/331218348435
```

Request for a Link:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/114961875194024
```

Request for an Album:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/10150146071791729
```

Is there a way to distinquish is request? That the first was for a note the second for an event etc?

Is the only way by comparing the returned fields?

Thanks.

**Found the solution:**

```
metadata=1
```

Adding this to the request will return a "type"=....

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found the solution:**

```
metadata=1
```

Adding this to the request will return a "type"=....

Answer (score 1):

If that is the way the API work then yes. Checking the return might be the only way.

Answer (score 0):

since the URL's are indistinguishable, there is probably something in the response